# What is the difference between "-gt 0" and "-eq $true" when looking for non-empty string values?

Tags: powershell

I'm gathering a list of all user accounts in AD that have a non-empty job title. First I get all the users (I'll filter later):

```
$allUsers = get-aduser -filter * -properties *
```

Then I grab only those accounts with non-empty Titles. First I tried the following thinking, "Well, if there is a value present it will evaluate to $true."

```
$allUsers | ? {$_.Title -eq $true}
```

But that results in an empty list. So then I tried what I thought was the same thing by doing the following:

```
$allUsers | ? {$_.Title -gt 0}
```

In this case I get the expected result.

What is the difference between the two statements? My thought is that PowerShell's -eq is like the === in JavaScript. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of the way that PowerShell tries to coerce the right hand side of a comparison to the type of the left hand side.

```psh
$allUsers | ? {$_.Title -eq $true}
```

This fails because it's the same as doing:

```psh
$allUsers | ? {$_.Title -eq "True"}
```

To see why, try casting: `[string]$true`

On the other hand, had you done this (**and I recommend you do**):

```psh
$allUsers | ? {$_.Title}
```

It would have worked as expected.

Similarly, when you do:

```psh
$allUsers | ? {$_.Title -gt 0}
```

This is like doing:

```psh
$allUsers | ? {$_.Title -gt "0"}
```

This is in theory a much more dangerous comparison, because a title that begins with, say `@` will return false. In practice, it's unlikely you'll have a title that begins with a character value lower than `0`, as all of the letters, upper and lower case, have a higher value. But I'm not accounting for internationalization.

> Though for my own sake, and the sake of those that come after me,
>   would you edit your post to explain exactly why {$_.Title} is the
>   preferable method?

I'm not saying it's absolutely the best but I like it for a few reasons:

- It's short.
- It doesn't contain any embedded constants. Not sure that it matters much, but it's less to get wrong.
- It's (in my opinion) clear what you are testing, since this is a common way for testing this in many languages.
- It works with `$null` and with an empty string.

There are other ways:

```psh
$allUsers | ? { ![String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Title) }
$allUsers | ? { $_.Title.Length -gt 0 }
$allUsers | ? { $_.Title -ne "" } # would include $null titles
$allUsers | ? { $_.Title -ne $null } # would include empty string titles
```

Something else I didn't address: you should be doing this comparison inside the `-Filter` property of `Get-ADUser` and ideally you should only ask for the properties you need:

```psh
$allUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter { -not (Title -like "*") } -Properties Title
```

The `-Filter` parameter looks like a script block but it has its own syntax and valid operators and values, so it's a bit tricky. This should be much faster though.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. Though for my own sake, and the sake of those that come after me, would you edit your post to explain exactly why {$_.Title} is the preferable method?